# jQuery Cycle plugin: scroll slides horizontally at constant speed, without easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-cycle, easing

I'm using [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). When I use `'scrollHorz'` as the value of `fx` property, slides move not at constant speed, but with easing (see [demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/Cycle/scrollhv.html)).

**How can I make the slides move at constant speed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
easing: "linear"
```

and you should be fine!
For example:

```
$('#s1').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    easing: 'linear',
    prev:   '#prev1', 
    next:   '#next1', 
    timeout: 0 
});
```